# How can I delete a custom ringtone exported from Garageband, after Garageband has been reinstalled?

Tags: iphone, garageband

A year ago, I downloaded the Garageband app to my iPhone 6S for the sole purpose of exporting a custom ringtone. I followed the instructions listed [on Apple's website](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12095?locale=en_US) and then deleted GarageBand, as I no longer needed it.

I now would like to delete this ringtone. Apple's instructions say this can be done within Garageband, but after redownloading Garageband and following the instructions, I am told I have no previously-exported ringtones!

I assume this is because I previously deleted Garageband? Something else? How can I delete this ringtone?

Comment: On your Mac, have your tried deleting it through iTunes... Devices > iPhone > Tones?

Comment: @user3439894 The ringtone doesn't appear there either! (But it's in the list in settings, I'm not going crazy, promise...)

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded my custom ringtones via iTunes, not GarageBand, but was hoping any custom ringtones added via an Apple app would be there. It's a shame it not the case. I'm going to +1 the question.

Comment: Have you tried using [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer)?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I created a test ringtone using GarageBand on iOS 12.2 using the directions linked in your post.

I then use [iExplore](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) to delete the file under Media > Purchases where there were three files on my device at that location, a Ringtones.plist file that had information about the .m4r file which had a GarageBand icon and a com.apple.ToneLibrary.lock file which was zero bytes in size.

Since this was the only file I've created with GarageBand and was indeed the file I created and was the only one in the Ringtones.plist file, I deleted both, leaving the com.apple.ToneLibrary.lock file, and then checked the iPhone and the ringtone was no longer available to be selected in Contacts or System Preferences in iOS.

---

Note: I am not affiliated with the developer of iExplore, Macroplant, simply a user of the product.

This was also done with just downloading and installing iExplore without purchasing it, as I currently do not need the paid functions.